# Alternatives for Google Talk and Cisco VPN?

Tags: software-recommendation, google-talk, cisco

Part 3 of my question.

I am trying to replace my Windows 7 system with a working Ubuntu system but I am running into issues with several software being used at work. Could anyone please advise alternatives for the following software / tools?

1. Google Talk using proxy ( empathy
   doesn't work with proxy servers)
2. Cisco VPN Client - (vpnc fails to
   connect and cisco linux vpn build
   locks up any dual core system after
   using it for some time).

Comment: I can perfectly connect to a Cisco VPN network---after having installed vpnc--- with the network panel. I just have to create a new VPN network choosing "VPNC cisco compatible" and set up everthing correctly.

Comment: Yes i think i have found my answer. I managed to connect with network manager vpnc . forgot to update the question/answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. How about Pidgin? It supports a wide variety of instant messaging protocols (eg. MSN, IRC, SILC, Yahoo..) and proxies as well.

Comment: doesnt work with the proxy. its very surprising though. all messengers gtalk, yahoo, digsby work through this proxy on windows but none work in linux

Comment: I will give this to you as i have finally managed to get Pidgin working through the proxy. :)

Answer (score 0):

**[QutIM](http://qutim.org/)**

> free open-source multiprotocol (ICQ, Jabber/GTalk/Ya.Online/LiveJournal.com, Mail.Ru, IRC) instant messenger

Answer (score 0):

Or may be you can use this handy trick, this would enable audio/video chatting http://tutafuta.com/2011/05/25/how-to-use-gtalk-on-linux-or-mac/

Answer (score 0):

@[Ubuntuser](https://askubuntu.com/users/9302/ubuntuser), are you sure you tried everything with vpnc? For instance, installing it on a kernel older than 2.6.38+, will result in compilation errors.
There are workarounds and patches; here's [a walk-through article](http://www.unfoldingcode.com/2011/08/how-to-install-cisco-vpn-client-on.html) that lead me to a successful install.